# Not Able to add TextTab

Tags: docusignapi

Hi I am able to send envelope by adding signhere tab but when i am trying to add TextTabs it is giving below error(I am using rest API's)

> **INVALID_REQUEST_BODY** The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Null object cannot be converted to a value type.

Below is my request JSON of envelope definition

```
{
"documents": [{
        "documentId": "1136641236",
        "uri": null,
        "remoteUrl": null,
        "name": "ABC Merchant Agreement",
        "password": null,
        "transformPdfFields": null,
        "fileExtension": null,
        "matchBoxes": null,
        "order": null,
        "pages": null,
        "documentFields": null,
        "encryptedWithKeyManager": null,
        "documentBase64": "documentBase64",
        "applyAnchorTabs": null
    }
],
"recipients": {
    "signers": [{
            "signatureInfo": null,
            "defaultRecipient": null,
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                        "name": null,
                        "tabLabel": null,
                        "scaleValue": null,
                        "optional": null,
                        "documentId": "1136641236",
                        "recipientId": "2044556663",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "xPosition": null,
                        "yPosition": null,
                        "anchorString": "SIGNATUREOWNER1",
                        "anchorXOffset": null,
                        "anchorYOffset": null,
                        "anchorUnits": null,
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": null,
                        "anchorCaseSensitive": "True",
                        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "True",
                        "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                        "tabId": null,
                        "templateLocked": null,
                        "templateRequired": null,
                        "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                        "conditionalParentValue": null,
                        "customTabId": null,
                        "mergeField": null,
                        "status": null,
                        "errorDetails": null
                    }
                ],
                "initialHereTabs": null,
                "signerAttachmentTabs": null,
                "approveTabs": null,
                "declineTabs": null,
                "fullNameTabs": null,
                "dateSignedTabs": null,
                "envelopeIdTabs": null,
                "companyTabs": null,
                "titleTabs": null,
                "textTabs": [{
                        "height": null,
                        "isPaymentAmount": null,
                        "formula": null,
                        "validationPattern": null,
                        "validationMessage": null,
                        "shared": null,
                        "requireInitialOnSharedChange": null,
                        "senderRequired": null,
                        "requireAll": null,
                        "name": "TextTab",
                        "value": null,
                        "originalValue": null,
                        "width": null,
                        "required": "true",
                        "locked": "false",
                        "concealValueOnDocument": null,
                        "disableAutoSize": null,
                        "maxLength": null,
                        "tabLabel": "gjk",
                        "font": null,
                        "bold": null,
                        "italic": null,
                        "underline": null,
                        "fontColor": null,
                        "fontSize": "Size12",
                        "documentId": "1136641236",
                        "recipientId": "2044556663",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "xPosition": null,
                        "yPosition": null,
                        "anchorString": "TEXTTABPLACEHOLDER",
                        "anchorXOffset": null,
                        "anchorYOffset": null,
                        "anchorUnits": null,
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": null,
                        "anchorCaseSensitive": "True",
                        "anchorMatchWholeWord": "True",
                        "anchorHorizontalAlignment": null,
                        "tabId": null,
                        "templateLocked": null,
                        "templateRequired": null,
                        "conditionalParentLabel": null,
                        "conditionalParentValue": null,
                        "customTabId": null,
                        "mergeField": null,
                        "status": null,
                        "errorDetails": null
                    }
                ],
                "numberTabs": null,
                "ssnTabs": null,
                "dateTabs": null,
                "zipTabs": null,
                "emailTabs": null,
                "noteTabs": null,
                "checkboxTabs": null,
                "radioGroupTabs": null,
                "listTabs": null,
                "firstNameTabs": null,
                "lastNameTabs": null,
                "emailAddressTabs": null,
                "formulaTabs": null
            },
            "signInEachLocation": null,
            "offlineAttributes": null,
            "requireSignerCertificate": null,
            "requireSignOnPaper": null,
            "canSignOffline": null,
            "isBulkRecipient": null,
            "bulkRecipientsUri": null,
            "recipientSuppliesTabs": null,
            "excludedDocuments": null,
            "name": "name",
            "email": "emailid",
            "emailRecipientPostSigningURL": null,
            "signingGroupId": null,
            "signingGroupName": null,
            "signingGroupUsers": null,
            "recipientId": "2044556663",
            "recipientIdGuid": null,
            "accessCode": null,
            "addAccessCodeToEmail": null,
            "requireIdLookup": null,
            "idCheckConfigurationName": null,
            "socialAuthentications": null,
            "phoneAuthentication": null,
            "samlAuthentication": null,
            "smsAuthentication": null,
            "userId": null,
            "clientUserId": null,
            "embeddedRecipientStartURL": null,
            "customFields": null,
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "idCheckInformationInput": null,
            "recipientAttachments": null,
            "note": null,
            "roleName": null,
            "status": null,
            "signedDateTime": null,
            "deliveredDateTime": null,
            "declinedDateTime": null,
            "sentDateTime": null,
            "declinedReason": null,
            "deliveryMethod": null,
            "faxNumber": null,
            "templateLocked": null,
            "templateRequired": null,
            "emailNotification": null,
            "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": null,
            "errorDetails": null,
            "recipientAuthenticationStatus": null,
            "totalTabCount": null
        }
    ],
    "agents": null,
    "editors": null,
    "intermediaries": null,
    "carbonCopies": null,
    "certifiedDeliveries": null,
    "inPersonSigners": null,
    "recipientCount": null,
    "currentRoutingOrder": null,
    "errorDetails": null
},
"customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [{
            "fieldId": "788788",
            "name": "AppNumber",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "value": "788788",
            "configurationType": null,
            "errorDetails": null
        }
    ],
    "listCustomFields": null
},
"eventNotification": null,
"brandId": "BrandId",
"allowRecipientRecursion": null,
"templateId": null,
"templateRoles": null,
"compositeTemplates": null,
"accessibility": null,
"transactionId": null,
"status": "sent",
"documentsUri": null,
"recipientsUri": null,
"asynchronous": null,
"envelopeUri": null,
"emailSubject": "ABC Agreement",
"emailBlurb": "Please Sign",
"envelopeId": null,
"signingLocation": null,
"customFieldsUri": null,
"envelopeIdStamping": null,
"authoritativeCopy": null,
"notification": {
    "useAccountDefaults": null,
    "reminders": {
        "reminderEnabled": "true",
        "reminderDelay": "1",
        "reminderFrequency": "2"
    },
    "expirations": {
        "expireEnabled": "true",
        "expireAfter": "2",
        "expireWarn": "1"
    }
},
"notificationUri": null,
"enforceSignerVisibility": null,
"enableWetSign": null,
"allowMarkup": null,
"allowReassign": null,
"createdDateTime": null,
"lastModifiedDateTime": null,
"deliveredDateTime": null,
"sentDateTime": null,
"completedDateTime": null,
"voidedDateTime": null,
"voidedReason": null,
"deletedDateTime": null,
"declinedDateTime": null,
"statusChangedDateTime": null,
"documentsCombinedUri": null,
"certificateUri": null,
"templatesUri": null,
"messageLock": null,
"recipientsLock": null,
"useDisclosure": null,
"emailSettings": null,
"purgeState": null,
"lockInformation": null,
"is21CFRPart11": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all

> Null object cannot be converted to a value type.

Remove the properties which have null value assigned to them. The following JSON should work.

```
{
  "documents": [
      {
          "documentId": "1136641236",
          "name": "ABC Merchant Agreement",
          "documentBase64": "documentBase64"
      }
  ],
  "recipients": {
      "signers": [
          {
              "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                      {
                          "documentId": "1136641236",
                          "pageNumber": "1",
                          "anchorString": "SIGNATUREOWNER1",
                          "anchorCaseSensitive": "True",
                          "anchorMatchWholeWord": "True"
                      }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                      {
                          "name": "TextTab",
                          "required": "true",
                          "locked": "false",
                          "tabLabel": "gjk",
                          "fontSize": "Size12",
                          "documentId": "1136641236",
                          "pageNumber": "1",
                          "anchorString": "TEXTTABPLACEHOLDER",
                          "anchorCaseSensitive": "True",
                          "anchorMatchWholeWord": "True"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "name": "name",
              "email": "emailid",
              "recipientId": "2044556663",
              "routingOrder": "1"
          }
      ]
  },
  "customFields": {
      "textCustomFields": [
          {
              "fieldId": "788788",
              "name": "AppNumber",
              "show": "false",
              "required": "false",
              "value": "788788"
          }
      ]
  },
  "brandId": "BrandId",
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "ABC Agreement",
  "emailBlurb": "Please Sign",
  "notification": {
      "reminders": {
          "reminderEnabled": "true",
          "reminderDelay": "1",
          "reminderFrequency": "2"
      },
      "expirations": {
          "expireEnabled": "true",
          "expireAfter": "2",
          "expireWarn": "1"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this model I got from DocuSign API documentation and I might want to use other properties in other scenarios like in some case I want to use anchor string feature and in some case, I may want to use X, Y positions to put tabs.So I can't remove those fields from my c# class of TextTab.If this null value is the issue then it should be the same issue for the signhere tab also but as I mentioned I am able to add signhere tab.

Comment: Did you try without setting the null value? What happens when you do that? Are you using the DocuSign [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client). Can you share your C# code.

Comment: Thank for your help, Issue has been resolved.The issue was like there was two property (hight, width) which was nullable int in my model but actually, those are not nullable from DocuSign side.When I set them null it's giving above error but when I set any integer value for those property able to send the document.